# Sending multiple mails in php where user has to enter the specific email id to which he has to interact with

Tags: html-email, form-submit, forms

Sending multiple mails in php where user has to enter the specific email id to which he has to interact with.

From the code below, I have created two email fields where one email is getting triggered (first one), but not with the second.

Can anyone help me solve it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>testing mail</title>

</head>
<body>

    <h1 class="text-center">Sending Emails</h1>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['sendmail'])) {
        if (mail($_POST['email'], $_POST['email1'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'])) 
        {
            echo "Mail sent";
        }else {
            echo "Failed";
        }   
    }
    ?>


            <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <label for="email">To Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" maxlength="500">

                        <label for="email1">To Email:</label>
                        <input type="email1" class="form-control" id="email1" name="email1" maxlength="500">

                        <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" maxlength="50">

                        <label for="name">Message:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message Here" maxlength="6000" rows="5"></textarea>

                    <button type="submit" name="sendmail" class="btn btn-lg btn-sucess btn-block">Send</button>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you compare the string:

```
emailall = $_POST['email']. ",".$_POST['email1'];
mail(emailall, $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'])
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

**Successfully working!!!!**.... Centralized email triggering to multiple email recipients!!!!!! (no default hard code required)where we can enter manually for specific email recipients where the whole form is been sent at the same time.

```html
<!--index.html-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Feedback Form</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: helvetica;
    }
    body{
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .main{
      width: 500px;
      margin: 50px auto;
      border-radius: 10px;
      border: 5px solid #0C3D6E;
      border-left: 40px solid #0C3D6E;
      box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px #555;
    }
    .info{
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #0C3D6E;
      padding: 7px;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #222;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .form-box{
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    label{
      color: navy;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    .inp,.msg-box{
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-top: 4px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 2px solid #0C3D6E;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #0C3D6E;
      border-right: 15px solid #0C3D6E;
      border-left: 15px solid #0C3D6E;
      resize: none;
    }
    .msg-box{
      height: 80px;
    }
    .inp:focus,.msg-box:focus{
      outline: none;
      border: 2px solid navy;
      border-right: 15px solid navy;
      border-left: 15px solid navy;
    }
    .sub-btn{
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      border: none;
      background: linear-gradient(#0C3D6E,#0C3D6E);
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #444;
    }
    .sub-btn:hover{
      background: linear-gradient(#0C3D6E,#0C3D6E);
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all ease-out 0.2s;
    }
    .sub-btn:focus{
      outline: none;
    }
    @media(max-width: 720px){
      .main{
        width: 90%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="info">Give Your Feedback!</div>
    <form action="mail_handler.php" method="post" name="form" class="form-box">
      <label for="name">Name</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required><br>

      <label for="phone">Phone</label><br>
      <input type="tel" name="phone" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Phone" required><br>

      <label for="email">Email ID1</label><br>
      <input type="email" name="email" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required><br>

      <label for="email">Email ID2</label><br>
      <input type="email" name="email1" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required>
      <br>

      <label for="email">Email ID3</label><br>
      <input type="email" name="email2" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required>
      <br>

      <label for="email">Email ID4</label><br>
      <input type="email" name="email3" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required>
      <br>

      <label for="email">Email ID5</label><br>
      <input type="email" name="email4" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required>
      <br>

      <label for="message">Message</label><br>
      <textarea name="msg" class="msg-box" placeholder="Enter Your Message Here..." required></textarea><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="sub-btn">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
**<!--mail_handler.php(php file)-->**

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $email1=$_POST['email1'];
    $email2=$_POST['email2'];
     $email3=$_POST['email3'];
      $email4=$_POST['email4'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $msg=$_POST['msg'];

    $to="$email, $email1, $email2, $email3, $email4"; // Receiver Email ID, Replace with your email ID
    $subject='Form Submission';
    $message="Name :".$name."\n"."Phone :".$phone."\n"."Wrote the following :"."\n\n".$msg;
    $headers="From: EHS@larsentoubro.com";

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
      echo "<h1>Sent Successfully! Thank you"." ".$name.", We will contact you shortly!</h1>";
    }
    else{
      echo "Something went wrong!";
    }
  }
?>
```